# MATLAB: How to read PRE tag and create cellarray with NaN

Tags: regex, matlab, nan

I am trying to read data from html file
The data are delimmited by `<PRE></PRE>` tag

e.g.:

```
<pre>
12.0  29132  -60.3  -91.4      1   0.01    260         753.2  753.3  753.2
10.0  30260  -57.9             1   0.01    260     58  802.4  802.5  802.4
 9.8  30387  -57.7  -89.7      1   0.01    261     61  807.8  807.9  807.8
 6.0  33631  -40.4  -77.4      1   0.17    260     88 1004.0 1006.5 1004.1
 5.9  33746  -40.3  -77.3      1   0.17               1009.2 1011.8 1009.3
</pre>

t = regexp(html, '<PRE[^>]*>(.*?)</PRE>', 'tokens');
```

where t is a cell of char

Well, now I would to replace the blank space with NaN and to obtain:

```
12.0  29132  -60.3  -91.4      1   0.01    260    Nan  753.2  753.3  753.2
10.0  30260  -57.9   Nan       1   0.01    260     58  802.4  802.5  802.4
 9.8  30387  -57.7  -89.7      1   0.01    261     61  807.8  807.9  807.8
 6.0  33631  -40.4  -77.4      1   0.17    260     88 1004.0 1006.5 1004.1
 5.9  33746  -40.3  -77.3      1   0.17    NaN    NaN 1009.2 1011.8 1009.3
```

This data will be saved on mydata.dat file

Answer (score 1):

If you have the HTML file hosted somewhere, then:

```
url = 'http://www.myDomain.com/myFile.html';
html = urlread(url);
% Use regular expressions to remove undesired HTML markup.
txt = regexprep(html,'<script.*?/script>','');
txt = regexprep(txt,'<style.*?/style>','');
txt = regexprep(txt,'<pre.*?/pre>','');
txt = regexprep(txt,'<.*?>','')
```

Now you should have the date in text format in `txt` variable. You can use [textscan](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to parse the `txt` var and you can scan for the whitespace or for the numbers.

More Info: 
 - [urlread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html)
 - [regexprep](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html)

Comment: Ok, thank you, but I have already read the data, I would to replace blank space with Nan how I explained above. Also with your solution I can't replace blank space because the data delimited by PRE have not a delimiter as TAB. The texscan fuction ignores the blank space.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the perfect solution but it seems to get you there.

Assuming t is one long string, the delimiter is white space, and you know the number of columns:

```
numcols = 7;
sample = '1  2  3  4  5    7  1    3    5    7';

test = textscan(sample,'%f','delimiter',' ','MultipleDelimsAsOne',false);
test = test{:}; % Pull the double out of the cell array
test(2:2:end) = []; % Dump out extra NaNs
test2 = reshape(test,numcols,length(test)/numcols)'; % Have to mess with it a little to reshape rowwise instead of columnwise
```

Returns:

```
test2 =

     1     2     3     4     5   NaN     7
     1   NaN     3   NaN     5   NaN     7
```

This is assuming the delimiter is white space and constant. Textscan doesn't allow you to stack whitespace as a delimiter, so it throws a NaN after each white space character if there isn't data present. In your example data there are two white space characters between each data point, so every other NaN (or, more generically, n_whitespace - 1) can be thrown out, leaving you with the NaNs you actually want.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I don't know always the delimiter, it can have more than 2 blank chars.

Comment: @Mixo is it constant?

Comment: the white space can be anywhere and not only one. In my example above, in the last line there are two white spaces (or empty positions)

Comment: @Mixo I'm asking about the delimiters, not the empty positions.